# Verify that points lie on a grid of specified pitch

Tags: numpy, floating-point

While I am trying to solve this problem in a context where numpy is used heavily (and therefore an elegant numpy-based solution would be particularly welcome) the fundamental problem has nothing to do with numpy (or even Python) as such.

The task is to create an automated test for an algorithm which is supposed to produce points distributed on a grid whose pitch is specified as an input to the algorithm. The *absolute* positions of the points do not matter, but their *relative* positions do. For example, following

```
collection_of_points = algorithm(data, pitch=[1.3, 1.5, 2])
```

`collection_of_points` should contain only points whose x-coordinates differ by multiples of 1.3, whose y-coordinates differ by multiples of 1.5 and whose z-coordinates differ by multiples of 2.

The test should verify that this condition is satisfied.

One thing that I have tried, which doesn't seem too ugly, but doesn't work is

```
points = algo(data, pitch=requested_pitch)
for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(points, 2):
    distance_between_points = np.array(p2) - np.array(p1)
    assert np.allclose(distance_between_points % requested_pitch, 0)
```

[ Aside for those unfamiliar with python or numpy:

- `itertools.combinations(points, 2)` is a simple way of iterating through all pairs of points
- Arithmetic operations on `np.array`s are performed elementwise, so `np.array([5,6,7]) % np.array([2,3,4])` evaluates to `np.array([1, 0, 3])` via `np.array([5%2, 6%3, 7%4])`
- `np.allclose` checks whether all corresponding elements in the two inputs arrays are *approximately* equal, and numpy automatically pretends that the `0` which is passed in as the second argument, was really an all-zero array of the correct size

]

To see why the idea shown above fails, consider a desired pitch of `3` and two points which are separated by `8.9999999` in the relevant dimension. `8.999999 % 3` is around `2.999999` which is nowhere near the required `0`.

In all of this, I can't help feeling that I'm missing something obvious or that I'm re-inventing some wheel.

Can you suggest an elegant way of writing such a check?

Comment: Surely, 8.9999999999 % 3 = 2.999999?

Comment: @Paul Yes, of course. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Change your assertion to:

```
np.all(np.logical_or(np.isclose(x % y, 0), np.isclose((x % y) - y, 0)))
```

If you want to make it more readable, you should functionalize the statement. Something like:

```
def is_multiple(x, y, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08):
    """
    Test if x is a multiple of y.
    """
    remainder = x % y
    is_zero = np.isclose(remainder, 0., rtol, atol)
    is_y = np.isclose(remainder, y, rtol, atol)
    return np.logical_or(is_zero, is_y)
```

And then:

```
    assert np.all(is_multiple(distance_between_points, requested_pitch))
```

Comment: I think you mean `isclose` rather than `allclose`, with `.all()` tagged on at the end. Also, you can replace `- y, 0` with just `, y` near the end. I had already done something similar in a loop. Yours is a bit shorter; mine is (I would argue) more understandable by a random passer-by. But the whole thing still feels too heavy and cryptic.